# Is there any easy way to transfer Windows 7 appearance tweaks?

Tags: windows-7

Over the years Ive made subtle changes to my windows 7 appearahce, from background color, the taskbar icon size, fonts and cleartype settings.  Is there any way to transfer all this, or do  I have to go through all this on the new comput r and try to replicate my settings?

Thanks!